# How to use the curly-braces-on-the-same-line style with compund function headers?

Tags: coding-style, curly-braces

I'm trying to adjust myself to the style of putting opening curly braces on the same line as the statement they belong to. Usually it looks good:

```
void foo(){
    //code
}
```

But when the function header is compound, and has code after the arguments list, it starts to look a little disturbing:

```
void foo() throws Exception{
    //code
}
```

And when the it gets so long you need to break it, it looks terrible:

```
void foo(int arg1,boolean arg2) throws ThisException,
                                       ThatException,
                                       AnotherException{
    //code
}
```

Ofcourse, compound function headers still look elegant in the curly-braces-on-their-own-line style, but I want to keep consistent coding style.

How do other users of the same-line style handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

do you really look for the opening brace? i see the name of the function and scan for the closing brace. The opening brace is just boilerplate

also, everything gets better with a whitespace ;)

```
void foo() throws Exception {
```

Comment: I'm a believer of the "making wrong code look wrong" ideology, so I don't like it when good code looks bad. About that whitespace - while it does improve the one line compound function header, it doesn't really help in the longer example...